# 読み込み完了の取得について

Tags: javascript, monaca, html, jquery, onsen-ui

現在、Monacaを利用したスマホアプリ開発を行っており、いくつかのページで
読み込み完了した時点で走らせたいロジックがあるのですが
どうやって取得するのかわかりません。

今までこの手は、$(window).load(function(){} で大体なんとかなりましたが
今回は ons-navigator にある ons-page 内の処理となり同じ手が使えないので
質問した次第です。

知りたいのは以下の２パターンです。

1.iframe内の外部サイト読み込み完了時
2.imgの読み込み完了時

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OnsenUIの初期化について](https://ja.onsen.io/v1/guide.html#UsingOnsenUIwithAngularJS)
どのように実装しているか分かりませんがAngularJSから呼び出している場合は
下記のようにすることでOnsenUIの初期化終了イベントを取得できます。

```
  module.controller('PageController', function($scope) {
    ons.ready(function() {
      // Init code here
    });
  });
```

---

**iframeの初期化について**

iframeにはonloadイベントがあるので
windowではなくiframeにloadを置いたらどうでしょうか？
本家SOの[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142837)も参考になるかと思います。

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
iframe.onload = function () {
    alert("iframe on laad.");
}
```

---

**画像の初期化について**
画像のソースを動的に変更するのであれば、スクリプト内で読み込み出来たか確認しましょう。
静的なものであれば、上記のiframeと同じ対処でもいいと思います。

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  console.log("start : " + (+new Date()));
  $("#target").attr({
    "src":"http://dummyimage.com/2000x2000/000/fff"
  }).one("load", function() {
    console.log("load complete : " + (+new Date()));
  }).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="target" src="">
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
ご提示いただいたやり方でどちらもできました。